# Drag and Drop from one window to another

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have been researching the Drag and Drop events that can be done but I can't seem to find anything about dragging and dropping between windows.

I can get it working if I have the box and paragraph in the one window, but it won't drop to the other browser. Please find my code below.

> DragElement.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
#div1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p id = "drag1" draggable = "true" ondragstart="drag(event)"> Hello </p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<script>
function drag(ev)
{
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function allowDrop(ev) 
{
    ev.preventDefault();
}
function drop(ev) 
{
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Homepage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
#div1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) 
{
    ev.preventDefault();
}
function drop(ev) 
{
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please refer this [link](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/). you may have some idea.

Comment: This link I have already looked at. It doesn't explain how to do it